# How does AWS charge for use of Fargate tasks?

Tags: aws-fargate

I have a Docker image that is running as a Fargate task. I am curious to know how AWS bills for the use of it. Currently I have a hard limit of 1GB and a soft limit of 512MB. If I bump the hard limit up to 2GB to avoid memory issue in certain cases, will I be charged for 2GB all the time or only the period that the container needs it? For most of time my application does not even need 512MB but occasionally it needs 2GB.

Answer (score 0):

Visit here for pricing details
https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/pricing/

The lowest vCPU is 0.25 which provides memory upto 2 GB and is charged based on the CPU utilized.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But what I am really wondering is say I have a task that 99% of time takes only 512MB memory, and only occasionally needs 4GB. If I set its soft limit to 512MB and hard limit to 4GB, how will I be charged? If my total computing time is 100, and say there is a spike of memory usage at minute 10 will lasts for 2 units, will I be charged 10*512MB + 90*4GB, or 98*512MB+2*4GB?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, so I asked AWS support about this since it is not clear from the documentation which memory setting is billed for. In short the answer I got was:
"The memory amount you are billed for is set by the task definition, rather than the hard memory limit of the container."